# jQuery.Deferred exception: Maximum call stack size exceeded RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: jquery, date

I have a problem with a part of my script from the Easy!Appointments software.

I get the following errors:

**jQuery.Deferred exception: Maximum call stack size exceeded RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Date.$P.toString [as _toString] (https://DOMAIN/panel//assets/ext/datejs/date.js:49:911)**

**Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded**

It seems **Date.today()** is not working (properly)..

Part of the code:

```
    $('#select-date').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        firstDay: 1, // Monday
        minDate: 0,
        defaultDate: Date.today(),

        dayNames: [
                EALang['sunday'], EALang['monday'], EALang['tuesday'], EALang['wednesday'],
                EALang['thursday'], EALang['friday'], EALang['saturday']],
        dayNamesShort: [EALang['sunday'].substr(0,3), EALang['monday'].substr(0,3),
                EALang['tuesday'].substr(0,3), EALang['wednesday'].substr(0,3),
                EALang['thursday'].substr(0,3), EALang['friday'].substr(0,3),
                EALang['saturday'].substr(0,3)],
        dayNamesMin: [EALang['sunday'].substr(0,2), EALang['monday'].substr(0,2),
                EALang['tuesday'].substr(0,2), EALang['wednesday'].substr(0,2),
                EALang['thursday'].substr(0,2), EALang['friday'].substr(0,2),
                EALang['saturday'].substr(0,2)],
        monthNames: [EALang['january'], EALang['february'], EALang['march'], EALang['april'],
                EALang['may'], EALang['june'], EALang['july'], EALang['august'], EALang['september'],
                EALang['october'], EALang['november'], EALang['december']],
        prevText: EALang['previous'],
        nextText: EALang['next'],
        currentText: EALang['now'],
        closeText: EALang['close'],

        onSelect: function(dateText, instance) {
            FrontendBookApi.getAvailableHours(dateText);
            FrontendBook.updateConfirmFrame();
        },

        onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, instance) {
            var currentDate = new Date(year, month - 1, 1);
            FrontendBookApi.getUnavailableDates($('#select-provider').val(), $('#select-service').val(),
                    currentDate.toString('yyyy-MM-dd'));
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was getting similar exception in below scenario and I was able to resolve it.

Jquery throws stack overflow exception while trying to get elements, elements are more than 130000.
Below line throws error

```
 $(dom).find(".elemCssClass")
```

above code line results below

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
at Function.se [as find] (app.js?typeSpec=hx%3AHxOrdTargetResolver&version=1622436777340:45)
at k.fn.init.find (app.js?....
```

I used `document.getElementByClassName(".class")`. it supports large number of elements in dom.